# Should I use WHERE clause after every part of an INNER JOIN, or it's better to stack them up at the end?

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join, innodb

I'm using MYSql and INNOdb. I've three tables (A, B and C) which I want to join them to get results. Their foreign keys are correctly related. Which one of the following queries is faster?

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.B_id=B.id
INNER JOIN C ON A.C_id=C.id
WHERE A.x=some_constant AND B.y=some_other_constant AND C.z=some_other_constant
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.y=some_other_constant) AS B ON A.B_id=B.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM C WHERE C.z=some_other_constant) AS C ON A.C_id=C.id
WHERE A.x=some_constant AND
```

Or perhaps, is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1):

It is logically different - are you constraining what goes into the join-set or are you creating a less constrained join-set and filtering that afterwards in a separate stage? This can actually give different results when you have left(outer) joins.

Logically constraining what goes into the join-set (putting constraints on the joins themselves) should also be faster but you are second-guessing the query optimiser which may be refactoring the query behind the scenes anyway. Test it out both ways, see if you can measure any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your first option is faster. At least if id is indexed correctly. In your second alternative, you create tables on the fly which may not carry the right indexes along. Usually you should avoid SELECT statements as Join sources.

There is a 3rd way which in your case will work:

```
SELECT * FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON (A.B_id=B.id AND B.y=some_other_constant)
  INNER JOIN C ON (A.C_id=C.id AND C.z=some_other_constant)
WHERE A.x=some_constant;
```

or even

```
SELECT * FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON (A.B_id=B.id AND A.x=some_constant AND B.y=some_other_constant)
  INNER JOIN C ON (A.C_id=C.id AND C.z=some_other_constant);
```

As pointed out by the comments and the other answer by @abasterfield, you should first make the query working and easy to read. Optimization is a later problem and with MySQL it often helps to really measure the different queries with your real data, since indexes and table size plays often a big role in query performance.

Comment: `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS` will show that the `ON` and the `WHERE` are often mapped to the same internal 'code'.  (But not when `LEFT` demands otherwise.)

Comment: Yes. Explain often helps a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use subqueries except where they are warranted; this is not such a case.

Do use the `ON` clause say how the two tables are 'related'.  This benefits the reader.

Put other conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  This also benefits the reader.

The first-mentioned query is the only one that satisfies these rules.

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.B_id=B.id
INNER JOIN C ON A.C_id=C.id
WHERE A.x=some_constant
  AND B.y=some_other_constant
  AND C.z=some_other_constant
```

In this particular example, the optimizer will look for an index starting with x or y or z and start with the corresponding table.  If it has multiple choices, it will apply further heuristics to figure out which table to start with.  Then it will "join" to the other tables, using (presumably) `PRIMARY KEY(id)` on the next table.

It is rare to have 3 tables in what appears to be a mutual 1:1 relationship.  I hope that your real test case is something different.  If you would like to start over with the real query and real `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`, we may give you a different answer!